# Is nVidia's Cg dead?

Tags: shader, cg

I like Cg but it seems to be a long way behind GLSL/HLSL now - only supporting fragment & vertex shaders, for instance.

Is it still being developed or has it been given up - in which case is there no longer a way to write GPU-independent shaders?

Comment: I see no reason this isn't a valid question, with a factual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is Cg still being developed? Yes; NVIDIA continues to update Cg and keep it in sync with technology.

Does that make it not "dead"? That's a subjective question.